# o365 oAuth Send and Receive email C#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, o365rwsclient

I am new to oAuth and looking to send and receive email for o365 Office.
I am a bit confused as I see some examples with EWS API and mentions that MS Graph is the accepted way. My application allows me to script code via .NET 3.5 (so I would be calling this library from within this environment). I am not sure how it will interact with dll library that is not 3.5/4.0   .

What is the correct way or library that I should use?
Are they any suggestions any one can provide like C# libraries to make this easier ?

Comment: I stumbled my way here from a comment you made in my answer. Is this for Wonderware? I've managed to submit emails through O365 by integrating the `MailKit` library to my system. I've run it on a System Platform 2017u2 Install and call the functions through ArchestrA graphics (not possible from WindowMaker itself as far as I know). You'd have to install .NET 4.7+ on the machines however

Comment: Yes it is, I would really like to see how you implemented it. I need to be able to use oAuth/365 for our systems to receive and read the email because simple mail is no longer allowed. I know how to create and use dll's in System Platform so anything would be great.  You call via the graphics,  I intend to call with an object (blue Dot) as I have some automated stuff I want to perform. Can you provide your examples? if need be pm me or link to the example.

Comment: @Grambot BTW I hope my comment was helpful. please see above - I forgot to use the user mention.

Comment: I did wrap the MailKit library in my own function library which I imported via Script Library to System Platform but I imagine you could do it without a wrapper. I assume you'll have to import `BouncyCastle.Crypto`, `Mailkit`, and `Mimekit` libraries at the minimum. Then follow the *Using MailKit* examples on their GitHub page for code. Wrap everything on try-catch and log the `error` variable which should give you enough info to work from. If I can find any notes about my implementation (done over a year ago) I'll try to make a better writeup here for you.